# Proper approach to manipulate v-if inside v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm newbie in Vue JS. My need is to manipulate v-if data inside v-for but the result not as I expected to matched the last array from split function, as shown below:

```
<tr v-for="list in lists.slice().reverse()">
            <td align="center">
              <span v-if="list.source_path.split('.').pop() == 'PNG'">
                  <img v-bind:src="list.source_path" height="100" width="100"/>
                </span>
              <span v-if="list.source_path.split('.').pop() == 'MP4'">
                  <video width='200' height="200" controls><source v-bind:src='list.source_path' type='video/mp4'></video>
                </span>
            </td>
</tr>
```

I believe that there is something wrong with the approach. Could you give me some guidance to fullfill my need?

**Edit**

The lists array:

```
[
 {
   "_id": "5afb828112e205917cb55abb",
   "task_id": 1526432385326,
   "source_path": "http://URL/fef27bbc50ae2dc8af6d5edfa34aedee_Android-PNG-Image.png",
   "status": 1,
   "time_start": "2018-05-16T00:59:45.326Z"
 }
]
```

Comment: Can you share your `lists` array?

Comment: @NafiulIslam please check the question again, I've updated it.

Comment: You're checking against `PNG` but your list.source_path is having `png`. That's why it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect the last item to return true for this: `v-if="list.source_path.split('.').pop() == 'PNG'"`

If so, then you should do `list.source_path.split('.').pop().toUpperCase()`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I got an insight that case sensitive should be considered when comparing string value.